# Django item swap

Tags: python, django

Please i need help implementing a feature in django where User A can request an item from User B and User B can choose to decline the request or choose to swap with one of User A items.

class item_request(models.model):

```
requester = models.foreignkey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

owner = models.foreignkey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

item = models.Foreignkey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

status = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="pending")
```